# ajax request to razor page using handler

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, mvvm

I am trying to get data from Active.cshtml.cs file using ajax call. 
Here is the jquery code:

```
var turl = '/Active?handler=Clients/' + id;
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: turl,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
           alert(JSON.stringify(result));
        });
```

Here is Active.cshtml.cs method

```
public JsonResult OnGetClients()
        {
        return new JsonResult("new result");
        }
```

The status is 200 Ok, but it shows the entire webpage in response. Ideally it should return "new result" in Network tab of developer tools. Is it that I have Active.cshtml and Active.cshtml.cs in Pages that creates the confusion? How can I resolve it?
Thanks

Comment: is this question related to razor pages in ASP.NET MVC

Comment: yes . its about how to handle ajax requests om razor pages

Comment: is it asp.net core

Comment: .net core 2.0 ..

Comment: asp.net core razor page you are asking about it right

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For razor pages, you should be passing the parameter value(s) for your handler method in querystring.

This should work.

```
yourSiteBaseUrl/Index?handler=Clients&53
```

Assuming your OnGetClients has an `id` parameter.

```
public JsonResult OnGetClients(int id)
{
    return new JsonResult("new result:"+id);
}
```

So your ajax code should look something like this

```
var id = 53;
var turl = '/Index?handler=Clients&id=' + id;
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: turl,
    success: function (result) {
        console.log(result);
    }
});
```